# django : Change default value for an extended model class

Tags: python, django, django-models

I posted a similar question a while earlier, but this one is different. I have a model structure of related classes like:

```
class Question(models.Model):
     ques_type = models.SmallIntegerField(default=TYPE1, Choices= CHOICE_TYPES)

class MathQuestion(Question):
     //Need to change default value of ques_type here 
     // Ex: ques_type = models.SmallIntegerField(default=TYPE2, Choices= CHOICE_TYPES)
```

I want to change the default value of ques_type in the derived class. How should i accomplish this?

Answer (score 15):

First, in this use of inheritance it is (at least according to my tests) not possible to change the default of the field in the child class. **`MathQuestion` and `Question` share the same field here, changing the default in the child class affects the field in the parent class.**

Now if what only differs between `MathQuestion` and `Question` is the behaviour (so, `MathQuestion` doesn't add any fields besides those defined in `Question`), then you could make it a [proxy model](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/topics/db/models/#proxy-models). That way, no database table is created for `MathQuestion`.

```
from django.db import models

class Question(models.Model):
     ques_type = models.SmallIntegerField(default=2)

class MathQuestion(Question):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self._meta.get_field('ques_type').default = 3
        super(MathQuestion, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    class Meta:
        proxy = True
```

Test:

```
In [1]: from bar.models import *

In [2]: a=Question.objects.create()

In [3]: a.ques_type
Out[3]: 2

In [4]: b=MathQuestion.objects.create()

In [5]: b.ques_type
Out[5]: 3
```

Comment: I am adding new fields in derived class. So proxy class method won't work.

Comment: Isn't it possible to set the ques_type field in __init__ method?

Comment: @Neo I tried, but according to the [documentation](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/topics/db/models/#field-name-hiding-is-not-permitted) this is not possible: **If a base class has a field called author, you cannot create another model field called author in any class that inherits from that base class.**

Comment: I'm not trying to over-ride by creating a new field, just trying to set a different "value" in init method. Isn't that feasible?

Comment: As mentioned in the first paragraph of my answer, I tried that and it affected the field of the parent class too, because they share the same object. Both field's default value became 3.

Comment: @Reiner Thanks a lot for your efforts. I guess I'll have to settle with over-riding the "save" method.

Comment: Please precise in your answer that this solution does not work. Calling the subclass' init function overrides the default value in the super class too.

Answer (score 5):

Examples above are for proxy models. If you need to change default for model inherited from non-abstract base model you can do following:

```py
from django.db import models


class Base(models.Model):
    field_name = models.CharField(...)


class Child(Base):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        kwargs['field_name'] = kwargs.get('field_name') or 'default value'
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

Which will set default if it wasn't passed directly on `Model(...)` or `Model.objects.create(...)`.

Answer (score 2):

This is easy to do using a closure.

from django.db import models

```
# You start here, but the default of 2 is not what you really want.

class Question(models.Model):
     ques_type = models.SmallIntegerField(default=2)

class MathQuestion(Question):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self._meta.get_field('ques_type').default = 3
        super(MathQuestion, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    class Meta:
        proxy = True
```

The closure allows you to define it how you like it.

from django.db import models

```
def mkQuestion(cl_default=2):
    class i_Question(models.Model):
        ques_type = models.SmallIntegerField(default=cl_default)

    class i_MathQuestion(i_Question):

        def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
            super(MathQuestion, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    return i_MATHQUESTION


MathQuestion = mkQuestion()
MathQuestionDef3 = mkQuestion(3)

# Now feel free to instantiate away.
```

Comment: Very good approach! It worked! In my case i had a default value generator which received a parameter from the class, the slug name for the class.

Answer (score 2):

Use a `Form` or `ModelForm`, on which you can override the field. For models, set the default value in it's `__init__` method like so:

```
class Question(models.Model):
     ques_type = models.SmallIntegerField(default=2)

class MathQuestion(Question):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MathQuestion, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.ques_type = 3

    class Meta:
        proxy = True
```

Note that this has to be done *after* calling the parent class init.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/