# Can a django model have a hardcoded no type field?

Tags: python, django, django-models

Basically my question stems from the need to create multiple models that branch off a main base class. Each of these models have a type, and I wish to keep this type on the model in the database, but I want to room for error so I thought of hardcoding it into the model.

This is pretty much a question of "Is this something that django supports?". I haven't fully tested this, I don't know / can't say that if I did this right now everything would be fine or not ... but I can't seem to find the relevant documentation for it and would like to learn the best practices.

Here is an example of what I mean:

```
from django.db import models
from enum import Enum


class PersonType(Enum):
    STUDENT = "Student"
    TEACHER = "Teacher"

class BaseClass(models.Model):
  """Represents a base model"""
  name = models.TextField()
  age = models.IntegerField()

class Student(BaseClass):
  """Represents a student"""
  type = PersonType.STUDENT.value

class Teacher(BaseClass):
  """Represents a teacher"""
  type = PersonType.TEACHER.value
```

Would something like this be accepted by django? The only other solution I can think of is to make type a `TextField` with the `default` property set, and never expose it via the serializer. There is no reason I can't do that, just checking that this could work as well since it's, aesthetically, more pleasing.

Comment: Yes, this will however not save anything to the database. This is just a class attribute, so `type` will not be saved, etc.

Comment: Oh, so in order to actually save it to the database, it has to be an instance of a django model field? Is this something that one learns from practice? Or are there any relevant docs you could point me towards.

Comment: @ÇağatayBarın that is good information, thank you! However, I don't think it addresses the question at hand. The question is regarding the `type` variable being allowed to be just a variable and being saved to the db. According to @Willem Van Onsem's answer, it seems this is not the case.

Comment: I've removed my comment and added an example for you. It fixes both problems on your code. I know you didn't ask for the model inheritance but that is much more important then the enum question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, your base class should be abstract because there's no point of having that table on database.

For the enum question, you should use CharField with choices.
Here's an example for you.

```
from django.db import models


PERSON_TYPE = (
  ('Student', 'Student'),
  ('Teacher', 'Teacher'),
)

class BaseClass(models.Model):
  """Represents a base model"""
  name = models.TextField()
  age = models.IntegerField()
  type = models.CharField(choices=PERSON_TYPE)
  
  class Meta:
    abstract = True

class Student(BaseClass):
  """Represents a student"""
  def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    kwargs['type'] = kwargs.get('type') or 'Student'
    super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

class Teacher(BaseClass):
  """Represents a teacher"""
  def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    kwargs['type'] = kwargs.get('type') or 'Teacher'
    super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

It might look like there's no point in using inheritance because both Student and Teacher models have the same fields. Although, you might need to add specific fields for each model and it'll come in handy for you to have a separation from the beginning.

Comment: I was literally typing an answer in regards to both of yours and @Willem Van Onsem's comment. The only problem I would have with this is that the type is now a `CharField` with the `choices` property. I don't wish to give the user the option to choose what they want. This will be broken into different views and so it will be clear if they are creating a student or a teacher. would having `type = models.TextField(default=PERSON_TYPE.STUDENT.value, blank=True)` be okay? `CharField`s require `max_length` to be defined, that's why I'm using `TextField`s

Comment: @MariosYiannakou just don't have the `type` field in your form and set it's value manually in the view. As for using `TextField`? It will work but why? The database will use the `max_length` set on the `CharField` and it will be more optimized (I don't believe the choices would have indeterminate length anyway)

Comment: I see. Very well then, thank you all for the information provided :D!

Comment: But if anyone in the future sees this, I would still like to know if it is possible to save the `type` on each of the models separately, reducing the work needed in the view (i.e. automatically save a `Student` model with the `Student` type).

Comment: Just made a quick search and found this.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/56340925/5186565
Changing my answer to also support this.

Answer (score 0):

Also, for anyone in the future not satisfied with the above. A more risky approach (risky as you need to remember to do this in every view when fetching the model, is to add this:

```
# TextField can be any instance of the `django.db.models` fields.
from django.db.models import TextField, Value

Students.objects.filter(...).annotate(type=Value(PersonType.STUDENT.value, TextField())
```

This gives you access to `student.type` as a field on the model, but is NOT stored in the database.